# "URL not in property" when I submit a removal request for an old subdomain's URLs to Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing, subdomain, url-removal

I have website called `example.com`. Somehow an admin URL `admin.example.com` was crawled (more than 2-3 years ago) and it has more than 150 search results.

Now the technology stack used to create that site is outdated. We remade the website with a completely new Technology stack.
Now I have `example.com/sitemap.xml` which doesn't have `admin.example.com` related URLs.

I want to submit a removal request for `admin.example.com` in my Google Search Console property for `example.com`.  However it says "URL not in property"

[image]

So how do I submit the removal request for the subdomain?  Are there alternatives to achieve this?  We will block or redirect `admin.example.com`, but how do we remove it from the Google search index?

Comment: How did you add your property? https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592 it seems that you must use DNS record verification

Comment: Seems @Martheen is correct. Need to create another `admin.example.com` domain property. Then need to add all removal requests for those. If can put answer then will accept it. Thanks

Comment: If your subdomain doesn't exist anymore or is serving error pages, Google will automatically remove the URLs as it crawls them.  It could take months to get to all of them.  Figuring out out to submit the removal request could significantly speed up the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Search Console doc](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592) mention two types of properties, URL-prefix and domain. This seems to be because Google doesn't recognize your subdomain, which according to your comment can be fixed by adding the subdomain as another property.